# How to stop push button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm newbie to develop iOS program and I need your help.

When i click on the button, my code checks a condition, if the condition is true, I want to access to the next `UIViewController` passing data with `prepareForSegue`, but if the condition is `FALSE`, I don't want to access to the next `VC` and stay on the current `VC`.

How could i do that?

When i click on my button, I directly access to the next `VC`, whatever the code in the `IBAction`. Is it possible to block the access?

I try to code that on a push button

```
- (IBAction)lancepartie:(id)sender {
...
```

Comment: show the whole method please

Comment: Nothing useful... It's just my condition.

Comment: Do you have both a segue and this action connected to the button in your storyboard?

Comment: You may want to start by doing some tutorials before posting questions on StackOverflow.com... This is iOS coding 101, and pretty much one of the first things you'll learn by picking up a book on iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers should work, but they kind of ignore the whole point of segues: you shouldn't have to manually set actions on buttons for things like segues. Instead, you should override the `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` selector.

To do that, you need to give your segue an identifier from Interface Builder, then add this code in your parent ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyIdentifier"])
    {
        return someCondition;
    }
    else return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)lancepartie:(id)sender {
    BOOL someConditionHasBeenMet = NO;
    // check condition
    if (someConditionHasBeenMet) {
         // push view controller
    } else {
         // nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: // push view controller     how could i do that? The launching to the newt VC is automatic, no ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
- (IBAction)lancepartie:(id)sender
{
    if(Your_Condition_Is_True){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your_Segue_Identifier" sender:sender];
    }
    else {
        //do not switch controller
    }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Your_Segue_Identifier"]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: How could i program to "do not switch controller" ?

Comment: if your condition is false the nothing will happen in following code. just do not write any code in else block. simple